# Xamarin forms APP throws System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable) while trying to fetch data

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin. Currently I'm trying to fetch data from asp.net web api.
As of for now I'm hitting google.com and trying to display whatever data is coming in a Label.

But My App fails with the exception mentioned above.
I've set permissions to access internet.

Please Help.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I have to vote to close this question. Please refer to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to read how to ask a proper question that yields a response.